# How to fix "ImproperlyConfigured" erros in django rest_framework urls.py

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out how django rest framework works and write some code. But i am getting

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'tutorial.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import

what is circular import? I can't understand. I created a app called **quickstart** inside i create **serializers.py** file.

quickstart/serializers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')
```

quickstart/views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

quickstar/urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import UserViewSet, GroupViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

testing/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [

    path('', include('quickstart.urls')),
    # path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

can you please describe why this error happened frequently?
Thank you!

Comment: should be `urlpatterns = router.urls.urlpatterns`.

Comment: not work still same error @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: the error says it is in `tutorials.urls`...

Comment: yeah. Do i need to add this testing/urls.py?

Comment: each app needs an `urls.py`. But normally it will construct that for you if you use the `django-admin`.

Comment: yes i use django-admin when creating testing project. I also add this code in question. why this error happened?

Comment: The exception says `tutorial.urls` and you didn't provide it. What does `tutorial/urls.py` look like ?